# como hacer que dos ImageTarget me lean el spirte que tengo seleccionado

Tags: unity3d, unity, unity2d, vuforia

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy usando dos imágenes iguales, lo que de distinto color para leerla AR de **Vuforia**. Al crear la base de datos, las definí cada una con un patrón, en este caso seria uno de color morado y el segundo de color rosado. Agregue dos **ImageTarget** en los cual definí un **Spirte** en cada uno de a cuerdo al color de la imagen.

Lo que me esta sucediendo es que siempre que leo uno o otro siempre me carga el mismo **Sprite** a pesar que son distinto. Lo que deseo es que cuando lea el morado me cargue el que responde a ese color y así con el otro.

Nota: No estoy usando ningún script para hacer esta acción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vuforia reconoce patrones de **lineas y formas**, no colores... ya que todo se hace en **escala de grises**,, entre más **contraste** haya en tus imágenes mejor será el reconocimiento...